# Is there log4net pattern format logs viewer?

Tags: log-files, log4j

Do you know a good free log viewer for existing log4net log files that were written using PatternLayout format?

I've found:

- LegitLogViewer (probably it is possible to configure that one)
- YALV!(xml)
- Log4View(paid)
- Log2Console (unstable)
- GamutLogViewer (free version shows only 1 line, unusable)
- Chainsaw(xml only?)
- LogExpert(xml)
- BareTail

but none of them aren't usable option.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577568/is-there-a-user-friendly-log4net-log-files-viewer

Answer (score 2):

I've found what I looked for! It is [LogJoint](https://logjoint.codeplex.com).

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: How were you able to get LogJoint work? I am using it with log files with an extension .log, it seems to load only one file at a time.